# Routing error - undefined method that I already defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I have been reading different all the different solutions regarding this issue related to Ruby on Rails but I couldn't fix it.
Here is the thing.

app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title = '')
    base_title = "Example"

    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      page_title + " | " + base_title
    end
  end
end
```

From views/layouts/applications.html.erb I do

```
<title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
```

The application.html.erb is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%=  full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I am getting

```
ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `full_title' for ApplicationHelper:Module):
```

It seems that from the layout I don't have access to a global method that I defined. 
Do I have to defined in another place in order to use it?

Thanks

Comment: What you have done should be fine... the confusing part is you are getting `RoutingError` instead of `ActionView::Template::Error`. I suspect that the problem lies elsewhere - perhaps post the rest of your application.html.erb in your question.

Comment: Just did @David. Thanks!

Comment: That looks fine to me ... just did a quick sanity test and used your layout and method and it works fine. Maybe try removing the call from the layout and see if it still throws that error. If it does still gives the error then obviously your problem lies elsewhere ... if it doesn't then something else is also a factor contributing to this issue and you will need to try and identify what that is. The fact you are getting a `RoutingError` and not simply a rendering error is what I would focus on - why would it attempt to route at all to `full_title`?

Comment: I have been trying different things, I started a new project only with the module inside of the application helper and I am still getting "undefined method `full_title' for ApplicationHelper:Module" so the problem is not in the application itself. Any idea where to look?